# On Delete Cascade fail

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables, first my Account table

```
DROP TABLE "Account" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; 
CREATE table "Account" (
  "Id" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "Name" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  "User" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  "Email" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  "Password" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  "Level" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Account_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

ALTER TABLE "Account"
  ADD UNIQUE ("Name", "User", "Email");

DROP SEQUENCE Account_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE Account_seq START WITH 0
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 10000;
```

Then insert some dummy data

```
INSERT INTO "Account" ("Id", "Name", "User", "Email", "Password", "Level") VALUES (Account_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Jan', 'Jan1993', 'jan1993@hotmail.com', 'password', 'user');
INSERT INTO "Account" ("Id", "Name", "User", "Email", "Password", "Level") VALUES (Account_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Piet', 'Piet1978', 'piet1978@gmail.com', 'password', 'admin');
```

And i have a Review table

```
DROP TABLE "Review" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; 
CREATE table "Review" (
  "Id" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "ReactionId" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "UserId" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "Score" NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  "Date" DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Review_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

ALTER TABLE "Review"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "Review_Reaction_fk"
  FOREIGN KEY ("ReactionId")
  REFERENCES "Reaction" ("Id")
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE "Review"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "Review_User_fk"
  FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
  REFERENCES "Account" ("Id")
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

DROP SEQUENCE Review_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE Review_seq START WITH 0
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 10000;
```

And again i insert some dummy data

```
INSERT INTO "Review" ("Id", "ReactionId", "UserId", "Score", "Date") VALUES (Review_seq.NEXTVAL, 1, 2, 1, SYSDATE);
INSERT INTO "Review" ("Id", "ReactionId", "UserId", "Score", "Date") VALUES (Review_seq.NEXTVAL, 2, 1, 0, SYSDATE);
```

When i remove a user with Id = 1 it deletes all the data in the Review table. But it should only delete the data where UserId = 1...

Comment: A good way to investigate such issues is to active SQL tracing (`ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=TRUE`).  A trace file will be produced on the server that will show all the SQL statements, including the recursive ones generated internally by Oracle, in your session.

Comment: I think the burden is on you to debug this. If you want some help from SO, you'll have to create a script or a sqlfiddle that reproduces the problem.  Otherwise, we can only guess, because the problem is clearly not within the parts of the script you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Only possible reason, I could guess is the mysterious constraint,

`"Review_Reaction_fk"`

it refers `Reaction`'s `"Id"` as foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE "Review"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "Review_Reaction_fk"
  FOREIGN KEY ("ReactionId")
  REFERENCES "Reaction" ("Id") ----> Here
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Perhaps, reaction table refers `"Account"` table, and it gets the record deleted, that "Review" refers.

Answer (score -1):

The "on delete cascade" option, during the first years of relational databases, was a nifty idea. You didn't have to worry about following relational links back to their origins. Just delete the entity and the system will do all the grunt work for you.

However, there are some serious drawbacks. The unintended consequences for one: "Wait! I didn't mean to delete all that other stuff." Then there is the locking. Before a row can be deleted, it must be locked. But if there are FK references to the row, those must be searched out and locked. If any of *those* have FK references, another level of "search out and lock" takes place. Again and again until everything is safely locked. The trouble is, it doesn't take very much of this to bring your entire database to a screeching halt. Everything is locked or waiting for a lock to be released.

I'm glad I'm not a DBA. It's times like these I'm *really* glad I'm not a DBA!

A few more problems like the one you are having may convince you the "on delete cascade" is generally a Bad Idea. You're probably a lot better off just taking the time to write the code to search out the chain of relationships and delete them in an intelligent manner. It will also give you the opportunity to show some "Are your sure?" second chance opportunities to the users. Just in case.